# Java String values not matching text after substring

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, substring

Got a bit of an odd problem. I have the following code to do some basic parsing of a String:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(i);

        //get time
        int firstWhiteSpace = line.indexOf(" ");
        String time = line.substring(0, firstWhiteSpace);

//problem is here vvvv
            line = line.substring(firstWhiteSpace + 1, line.length());
//problem is here ^^^^

        //get client
        int firstColon = line.indexOf(":");
        String client = line.substring(0, firstColon);
        line = line.substring(firstColon + 1, line.length());

        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.setTime(time);
        chatMessage.setClient(client);
        chatMessage.setMessage(line);

        messages.add(chatMessage);
    }
```

So basically after I do `line = line.substring(a, b)` I would expect to get a substring of line between `a` (inclusive) and `b` (exclusive). However, if I print `line` I get the entire String prior to performing the substring operation. Curiously if I look at the debugger (Eclipse) then the value of the String IS the substring BUT the character array contains the entire String.

For example, if:

```
line = "Hello World"
```

and I do:

```
line = line.substring(0, 5);
```

then line now has a value of:

```
"Hello"
```

but the character array is:

```
[H, e, l, l, o, , W, o, r, l, d]
```

Hence, I'm a little confused. Apologies if I've missed something ridiculously stupid. Which is quite possible.

The full code, its not a very complicated class:

public class ChatParser {
    private static TS3ParserSettings settings;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChatParser.setSettings("C:/Users/*****/javaWorkspace/TS3Parser/src/data/settings.txt");
    ChatParser.parseChat();
}

public static void parseChat() {
    ArrayList<String> lines = TextParser.parseTextLines(settings.getSetting("chatLogPath"));
    ArrayList<ChatMessage> messages = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(i);

        //get time
        int firstWhiteSpace = line.indexOf(" ");
        String time = line.substring(0, firstWhiteSpace);
        line = line.substring(firstWhiteSpace + 1, line.length());

        //get client
        int firstColon = line.indexOf(":");
        String client = line.substring(0, firstColon);
        line = line.substring(firstColon + 1, line.length());

        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.setTime(time);
        chatMessage.setClient(client);
        chatMessage.setMessage(line);

        messages.add(chatMessage);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("TIME = " + messages.get(i).getTime() + " CLIENT = " + messages.get(i).getClient() + " MESSAGE = " + messages.get(i).getMessage());
    }
}

public static void setSettings(String path) {
    settings = SettingsParser.parseSettings(path);
}
}
```

Comment: What character array are you talking about?

Comment: Where is the println()'s for the `String` or `char[]`? I have the feeling something is missing. Maybe a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Yes... can we have a look to your whole code? It would be easier to get what you are saying u post that complete code..

Comment: Store lines.size() in a variable and use that variable in for loop's condition. Performance tip..!

Comment: Sorry, maybe the wrong term. I'm just confused because the Eclipse debugger says the value field of the String object contains all of the characters prior to substring being called.

Comment: Added the full code. Its not very complicated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but using the String method `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` could simplify this code (don't do line = line.sub...)

Comment: OK. I solved the problem. It was a silly error but thank you for the advice and telling me a few things about String objects that I didn't know. :)

Comment: What was the silly error?  It's always good to leave the explanation here for people who might have made the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Since `String` objects are immutable, the compiler is free to share the underlying data.  When you do a `substring()`, you create a new String reference object that points to the original string array but has a different starting offset and length.

As to the first example, print out the value of `firstWhiteSpace` and I think all will become clear.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The returned array should contain the string as-is. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: @Martin - "returns a new string" only means that a new String object is returned.  The compiler/jvm are free to reuse the underlying char array, as the data there can never be modified.

Comment: No, you misread the javadoc. It says: "Converts this string to a **new** character array."

Comment: I'm looking at the Java 7 Javadoc for `String#substring(int,int)` and don't see any thing about a "new character array".  Those three words occur together only in the definition of `toCharArray()`.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Yes, the substring method shares the data, but he is talking about the character array that doesn't match the substring he is trying to take.

Comment: @noise256: You can add an answer by yourself and accept it within two days.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with immutability: If you have a collection/array of objects, changing the value of a local variable that holds a reference to on of the objects has no effect on the collection/array.

This code demonstrates:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
String localVar = strings.get(0); // "foo"
localVar = "hello"; // this only affects localVar
// strings is still {"foo", "bar"}
```

FYI, what you call an "array" is an `ArrayList`, which *uses* an array, but is not a java "array".